# Advice on how to go about splitting a form into multiple "pages"/"tabs" in Vue?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, frontend, bootstrap-vue

I'm new to Vue development and I was hoping to get some advice or a better solution to a problem I am trying to solve.

At the moment I am trying to build a wizard tool that can take in 1 form that spans multiple pages (within the wizard). How I hope for it to behave would be something like:

```
  <myWizard>
    <form>
      <myPage>
        <label />
        <input/>
      </myPage>
      <myPage>
        <label />
        <input/>
      </myPage>
    </form>
  </myWizard>
```

My main problem is basically since it is a tool I do not know/have what is between the `<myWizard>` tags since it depends on the person using the tool.

I already have a base setup that can render content into separate tabs(pages) using BootStrap, but wondering what would be the best way to handle separating of the form contents into different pages.

For example would something like using a `<slot>` to take in everything between the `<myWizard>` tags then having myPage be another component that would allow me to render whats between them into separate pages in the wizard?

Though doing this and trying to identify "tags"/"components" inside the slot seems very roundabout and isn't something I have specifically looked into yet.

Thanks for any advice tips you may have.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
// router.js
const vueRoutes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
  },
(...)
  {
    path: '/wizard',  // Define main route for the form
    name: 'wizard',
    component: AppWizard,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'page1',
        name: 'page1',
        component: FormPart1, // If the route is '/wizard/page1' it will render the FormPart1 component
      },
      {
        path: 'page2',
        name: 'page2',
        component: FormPart2, // If the route is '/wizard/page2' it will render the FormPart2 component
      }
    ],
  },
(...)
]

// AppWizard.vue
<template>
  <my-wizard>
    <form>
      <router-view>
    </form>
  </my-wizard>
</template>

// FormPart1.vue
<template>
  <fieldset>
    <label1/>
    <input1>
    <label2/>
    <input2>
  </fieldset>
</template>


// FormPart2.vue
<template>
  <fieldset>
    <label3/>
    <input3>
    <label4/>
    <input4>
  </fieldset>
</template>
```

Of course, you are free to replace `wizard/page1` with `pages/1` or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, though I'm probably a little confused would this mean to setup the form it would be pretty static since the form held in the wizard would always be the form I myself have built?

Just realized I didn't mention it but I was hoping to have wizard be a tool to create wizards. So things like the number of pages and the actual contents of the form I do not know.

Comment: Well, that is a completely different story :-D

Comment: You could try dynamic routing https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes  coupled with ESM dynamic `import()`